# Open File Dialog box using "for" attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, openfiledialog

I want to have an Open File dialog box on a link in master page.
it worked in my web page, but not working in master page.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
        <div class="img-uploader left">
            <label id="img-upload-trigger" for="FileUploadPic">
                <img src="img/image.png" alt="">
            </label>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadPic" onchange="this.form.submit()" runat="server" />
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working in the master page? It doesn't submit the form? What error do you receive?

Comment: not get the error doesn't submit the form

Comment: it should work fine if the only change is moving the uploader to the content page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using ClientIDMode="Static" in your server control

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <div class="img-uploader left">
        <label id="img-upload-trigger" for="FileUploadPic">
            <img src="img/image.png" alt="">
        </label>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadPic" onchange="this.form.submit()" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
    </div>
```